# How to specify LifeCycle Listener listener class in web.xml?

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I want to get notified once the server got started successfully.. For that I have added the below in the web.xml

```
<listener>    <listener-class>com.server.container.Listeners</listener-class> </listener>
```

Listeners is class which implements org.apache.catalina.LifecycleListener.

Is this correct? As of now i am not getting any notification during server startup end. Do i need to do anything extra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In J2EE, Listener notifies whenever some action (context created, destroyed, request or session attribute added, removed, etc..) happens on the server.

Please find the below sample listener code below:

**ApplicationListener  Class (in your project):-**

```
package com.myproject;

import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;

public class ApplicationListener implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(" Server Starting !!!!!! ");

        //Any other code you can place here
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println(" Server Shutting down !!!!!! ");
    }
}
```

**web.xml changes:**
Add below code to your web.xml

```
<listener>
        <listener-class>
             com.myproject.ApplicationListener 
        </listener-class>
   </listener>
```

Also, please ensure that you have got "servlet-api.jar" file in your classpath.

Comment: i want to get notified once the server startup completes. The above contextInitialized will be called during the startup to init our contexts class. I want notification after the complete server startup. is that possible

Comment: May I know, what is the exact action, you wanted to do with the notification  after server start up ?

Comment: Yes.. after the server startup i need to create http request to the localhost(same) server via code.

Comment: Write a StartupServlet class and inside the init() method of the StartupServlet, you can place your code (i.e., create http request). Ensure that you are adding <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> for your StartupServlet, means that this servlet init() will be called immediately after the server start up.